# Delphi> Please explain this: type... procedure of object

Tags: delphi

I've encountered some code that's new to me...

I've never really seen a **type declaration of a procedure of object**, and I just don't 
see the point. 
Why couldn't the developer simply keep a field of type Boolean?

```
interface

    type
      TFinishedCaptureEvent = procedure(AFinished: Boolean) of object;

      TFrameCard = class(TFrame)
      ...
      private
        FOnFinishedCapture: TFinishedCaptureEvent;
        procedure DoUpdateMessage(AMessageType: TMessageType);
      public
        property OnFinishedCapture: TFinishedCaptureEvent read FOnFinishedCapture write FOnFinishedCapture;
      end;    

implementation

...

procedure TFrameCard.DoUpdateMessage(AMessageType: TMessageType);
begin
  if Assigned(FOnFinishedCapture) then
    FOnFinishedCapture(False);
  ...
end;

end.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far, but they're too academic for me. Can you explain this in a way that I can understand? The developer could have just declared a boolean property of the form/frame that reads and writes to a boolean field of the form/frame.

Comment: @Richard If it was done as a property then it would deny the opportunity of multi-threading and, more importantly, would force the client (that which supplies the event handler) to have intimate knowledge of the object that fires the event.

Comment: Thank-you, I think I'm beginning to get it now :)

Comment: To add a little more clarity - the real benefit here is that the client app can be immediately notified when the (perhaps lengthy) process in TFrameCard is finished doing whatever it is doing, whilst also being notified of the value of the AFinished parameter.

Comment: @Stuart        Thanks, I had started to suspect something like that... I have a TForm (TFormSales) with a Frame(TFrameCard) which also has a  Frame(TFrameCardList).

The TFrameCardList uses this functionality to send a message to the TFrameCard. The TFrameCard in turn sets this FOnFinishedCapture property. I now have to get it so that TFormSales gets this message. I learnt something today, although it's still not 150% clear, I think it's something I'll have to fathom a bit more...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A `procedure of object` is a procedure reference for procedures contained in class instances. When calling procedures that are members of a class, the implict `Self` reference must be passed with the other parameters. Using `procedure of object` tells the compiler to store the `Self` reference with the procedure address inside the procedure reference, so that when the procedure is called via the procedure reference, the `Self` reference will be automatically passed.

In the code snippet you provided, `TFinishedCaptureEvent` is defined as a procedure of object, meaning that any variables created of its type will contain 2 values: the `Self` value and the procedure address. When this variable is assigned to, in particular when the assignment is inside a class, the compiler will automatically set the Self value inside this variable to the instance of the class that contains the procedure being assigned to the variable. When the variable is called (`FOnFinishedCapture(False)`), the compiler automatically passes the correct `Self` value back to the procedure that was assigned to this variable.

Comment: Thank you, I think I'm beginning to get it now :)

Answer (score 21):

Let's break this down into two parts to be easier to understand.  First, `procedure(AFinished: Boolean)` isn't a `boolean` variable, it's a reference to a procedure that takes a boolean as a parameter.  It's basically a procedure header, except without the procedure name because this is just a type definition.  Any procedure that matches this signature can be assigned to this variable.

The `of object` part means that this isn't just a procedure reference, but a *method reference*; it has to belong to an object.  The compiler needs to know the difference so that it can store the `self` pointer for the object together with the procedure pointer so it can be invoked properly, as the other posters have pointed out.

Basically, this is declaring a new event handler, and it's a pretty common pattern in Delphi.  It's the same thing that the VCL does all over the place.  When you create a button and assign an `OnClick` handler, it has to be a `procedure (Sender: TObject) of object;`.  Your form gives the button a method reference referring to itself and the event handler procedure, and then the button uses that information to invoke the handler on the form when someone clicks it.

This code is doing the same thing.  It's providing a way for some external object to be notified when DoUpdateMessage runs, using the standard Delphi idiom for event notification.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand how you relate this to a field of boolean.

But `TFinishedCaptureEvent = procedure(AFinished: Boolean) of object` declares a delegate/method pointer type, which is used for events. It's a `record` which contains a `self` pointer and a function pointer. When you call the delegate, the function is called with the `self` passed as a parameter to the function.