# Saving a pointer to specified function in Delphi

Tags: delphi, function, function-pointers

Not sure if the tittle is right but what I need to do is to store in some collection a pointer to specified function. I'm doing that pretty much like declaring a variable

```
SomeFunctionName: string
```

Of course this type can't be a string, the question is what should it exactly be?

Comment: `type TGetSomeString = function : string; // read on procedural types in the documentation`

Comment: Typically, for methods (procedure or function that belongs to a class) you would use type `procedure(args) of object` or `function(args):resultype of object` plus the type declaration. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626614/delphi-please-explain-this-type-procedure-of-object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would typically use a function pointer variable. For example:

```
type
  TProcedure = procedure;

procedure MyProc1;
begin
end;

procedure MyProc2;
begin
end;

var
  Proc: TProcedure;

.....
Proc := MyProc1;
Proc();//calls MyProc1
Proc := MyProc2;
Proc();//calls MyProc2
```

This is the most simple example imaginable. You can specify procedural types that have parameter list, method of object types and so on. Read more in the [Procedural Types](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Procedural_Types) topic of the language guide.

Comment: @TLama Yes I've seen it from time to time. I have reported it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125587/please-can-this-markdown-bug-be-fixed

Comment: @JacekKwiecień See the section named "Method Pointers" in the page that David refers to.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually not storing procedure / function but storing method.

So you should use TMethod Instead.
A TMethod has a object pointer and a procedure pointer.

You can see more detail in another post :
[Save and restore event handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9585956/save-and-restore-event-handlers/9587812#9587812)

edit : It seems the question has been edit back to original after showing some Storing TControl.onClick event request.....